# legend matching the line type in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

With the code below I get a plot for two datasets. The `geom_line` for the first data is dotted line. However, in legend it doesn't appear as such.

```
library(ggplot2)
A = data.frame(x = rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))
B = data.frame(x = rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))

ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = A,aes(x,y,colour = "cat"),linetype = 2)+
  geom_line(data = B,aes(x,y,color = "dog"))+
  scale_colour_manual("", 
                      breaks = c("cat", "dog"),
                      values = c("blue", "red"))
```

How do I get the legend as dotted line for `cat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OP asked about how to specify that "cat" gets a dashed line, I will add to the other answer to say that you should combine the data frames, but then you can use `scale_linetype_manual()` to specify the association of linetype to each factor of `df$animal`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- A %>% 
  mutate( animal = "cat") %>% 
  bind_rows(B %>% 
              mutate( animal = "dog"))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, linetype=animal)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c('dog'='solid','cat'='dashed'))
```

The other way to do this is to **NOT** combine the data frames.  This approach is discouraged, but it does still work and also still requires you to use `scale_linetype_manual()` to specify which linetype goes with each.  In this case, the name of the label for each linetype is defined within `aes(linetype=`, rather than via a column created in a new dataset.

```
# without combining data frames
ggplot(mapping=aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_line(data=A, aes(linetype='cat')) +
  geom_line(data=B, aes(linetype='dog')) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c('dog'='solid','cat'='dashed'))
```

Both approaches yield the same plot (differences may be observed due to different randomization seed):

[image]

Comment: Yes, you just need to include `color=` within `aes()` where there is also `linetype=`, and apply it in an identical way as for linetype.  So, in the first example, the aesthetics become: `aes(x=x, y=y, linetype=animal, color=animal)`, and you then add the scale function: `scale_color_manual(values=c('dog'='red', 'cat'='blue'))` to have the colors applied as per your specification.

Comment: Without combing data frames, your code becomes: `geom_line(data=A, aes(linetype='cat', color='cat'))`, then similarly follow the same suite for the second `geom_line()` call for "dog".  The `scale_color_manual()` function is the same as indicated above.

Answer (score 1):

For cases like this it is better to combine `A` and `B` into a new dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- A %>% 
  mutate( animal = "cat") %>% 
  bind_rows(B %>% 
  mutate( animal = "dog"))

ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = df ,aes(x,y,colour = animal, linetype = animal))
```